# Floating div with iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am attempting to float an iframe of some weather information on the bottom left hand corner of my site. I have the sizing and everything set together, but I am not too sure on what I am doing when it comes to floating it properly from within a div. I cannot seem to get the div and iframe to float nicely on the bottom left hand side of the site.

After many google searches and searches on here as well, I have kinda glued the following together:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom:3px; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; border: 0px none; width:270px; height:370px;">
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
</div>
<iframe src="http://weather.gc.ca/wxlink/wxlink.html?cityCode=on-162&amp;lang=e" scrolling="no" style="height: 300px; border: 0px none; width: 165px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 24px;">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

You can view what it is I am trying to accomplish here: http://www.soozoo.ca

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/MqEhF/

HTML

```
 <div style="left: 0px; border: 0px none; height: 370px; position: fixed; width: 270px; overflow: hidden; bottom: -67px;">
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
    <iframe src="http://weather.gc.ca/wxlink/wxlink.html?cityCode=on-162&amp;lang=e" scrolling="no" style="height: 300px; border: 0px none; width: 165px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 24px;">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That worked great. I see how you were able to correct it by fixing the position. Lesson learned, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make the position of the div "fixed".

Hope that works!!!